# Connection failed: Access denied for user ''username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to connect to MySQL on the server but gives following error. User is created and granted all privileges.

**It's working on local machine but not after deploying to a server.**

Also `mysql_connect` function works but `new mysqli()` gives access denied as mentioned below.

Also Tried adding port.

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''usernam'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/domainname/public_html/autopublish/test.php on line 8
> Connection failed: Access denied for user ''username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "'xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxx";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);  **//line 8**
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo "no connection";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    $data = array();
    $arr = array();
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Token";
    }
    print_r(json_encode($data));
    $conn->close();
    
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the user does not have the required rights for the database or the password is wrong.

Otherwise remove the user and use the following statement to create:

```
1.CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456789';
2.
3.GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON project.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or try this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
//Create
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

echo "Yaaay";
```

Comment: I have create new user and granted all permission.

Comment: It works with this mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password"); but not with mysqli()

Comment: You can try to change localhost to your local IP adress.

Comment: Yeah, its either local or external, not both.

Comment: Its on hosting server. I have also used ip and ip with port.