# Can't connect to mysql database without 'access denied'

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body> 
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "guest";
$password = "#Guest123";
$database = "My_first_Database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

When uploaded to my web server the page displays:

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'guest'@'localhost' (using 
>       password: YES)

I know issues like this are usually due to the 'guest' not having the correct privileges but 'guest' has all privileges on this database. So I don't understand why I cant access the database with this user.

I'm sorry if this has been asked here before, but everyone say to give the user privileges (which I have done).

Solved: mysql wasn't correctly granting all privileges when using GRANT ALL. Had to manually grant privileges

Comment: Are you using the right password? PS: posting your password on a public forum is an extremely bad practice.

Comment: Well, I really hope "#Guest123" isn't his password.  This error, usually, though, is because the password is incorrect or some other authentication issue. ;)

Comment: The server is localhost so it honestly doesnt matter that he post a password

Comment: That's fairly disingeunous ... what if the same credentials work on port 3306?  It's generally good practice to redact credentials whenever they're posted in public.

Comment: Why does the error say `Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'` when `$username = "guest";` in the code? Is the code that is being executed same as the one posted here?

Comment: Its not the real password.

Comment: It is good practive to remove crednetials no doubt but im pretty sure this isnt his actual vals (hopefully) but unless ur some super smart geek im sure hes safe

Comment: Have your DB administrator ensure that you have been granted credentials for 'username'@'localhost'.

FlamingGenius, I see your point, but that's "Security by Obscurity" and therefore should not be encouraged, nonetheless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection failed: Access denied for user ''username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504065/connection-failed-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-passwor)

Comment: @FlamingGenius If the body of the question is to be relied upon, then it appears that the server is _not_ localhost (OP seems to suggest that they _uploaded_ the code to the web server). It may just be so that the webserver possibly allows accessing the DB by referring to the host as `localhost`, instead of necessarily mandating the user to use an IP or network name. On the other hand, it may also very well be the issue that server wants IP / hostname and gets to see `localhost` in the connection string instead.

Comment: I have used GRANT ALL ON My_first_Database.* TO 'guest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '#Guest123' to give all privileges and checked the password and username are correct

Comment: Solved: mysql wasn't correctly granting all privileges when using GRANT ALL. Had to manually grant privileges

Comment: @KangarooChief rather than editing your question, you can supply your own answer to outline to future visitors what the issue was and how you overcame it. `:-)`

Comment: It says my answer isn't good enough quality so I just edited the post

Comment: @KangarooChief that sucks. I havemade an answer with your comments, it's a community answer so I don't get rep from it, feel free to edit the answer to make it clear how you discovered the issue and how you fixed the issue. `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have used `GRANT ALL ON My_first_Database.* TO 'guest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '#Guest123'` to give all privileges and checked the password and username are correct

--  KangarooChief

> **Solved:** mysql wasn't correctly granting all privileges when using `GRANT ALL`. I had to manually grant privileges

--  KangarooChief

Answer (score -1):

As far as your code goes everything is correct this is definitely a server issue going on here make sure your putting in the right values and privileges

*The below only implies if your setting up a home server*
check and make sure you have `read` and `write` access to the directory if the folder in which your database is setup does not have read and write access authentication will fail every time this is a common reason you may recieve an error telling you "Access Denied"

Double check your username,password,db for common misspellings

Comment: If he is setting up his own home server then he woukd need to allow his scripts read and write priveleges else it could fail

Comment: Edited to clarify :)